# RecyclerView and EditText.setOnFocusChangeListener

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

There is a RecyclerViewCursorAdapter in which EditText is located. It records the quantity of goods for the order.

Need to save the data from the input field after the change (in this case, after losing the focus. About TextChangedListener also thought, but for the time being stopped on this option), write changes to the database (to not accidentally lose data) and duplicate in SparseIntArray (stores the amount for dynamic), and do the conversion of the amount on the page into a separate activity element.

I tried adding the holder.editText.setOnFocusChangeListener to the onBindViewHolder, the recyclerview data is updated normally, but it's not clear how to work with the view contents of the activity to recalculate and display the summ and quantity in the item in the basket?

p.s. programming is more of a hobby than a profession. I will be grateful for any idea.

Comment: did you try interface callback?

Comment: Thank you. The interface in activity solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create an interface

```java
public interface RecyclerViewEditTextChanged {
    void onPriceChanged(int price);
}
```

2. In activity, before initializing the adapter, implement the interface:

```java
RecyclerViewEditTextChanged recyclerEditTextChanged = new RecyclerViewEditTextChanged(){
        @Override
        public void onPriceChanged(int price){          
                priceTextView.setText(price);
        }
}
```

3. In the recyclerview adapter, in addition to context, pass the interface from step 2.

```java
adapter = new RecyclerViewCursorAdapter (getContext(), recyclerEditTextChanged);
```

4. implement callback in adapter

```java
private final RecyclerViewEditTextChanged recyclerEditTextChanged;
public RecyclerViewCursorAdapter (Context context, RecyclerViewEditTextChanged listener){
    this.context = context;
    this.recyclerEditTextChanged = listener;
}
```

5. transfer data through the interface in activation

```java
holder.editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            recyclerEditTextChanged.onPriceChanged(Integer.parseInt(holder.editText.getText().toString));
        }
    });
```